# How to extract the inner text and XML of node as string?

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing

I have the following XML structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
  <node1>
    <subnode1>
      <value1>101</value1>
      <value2>102</value2> 
      <value3>103</value3> 
    </subnode1>
    <subnode2>
      <value1>501</value1>
      <value2>502</value2> 
      <value3>503</value3> 
    </subnode2>
  </node1>
</main>
```

In Delphi I am looking for a function which returns the inner text and XML of a node as a string. For example for `<node1>` the string should be (if possible including indents and line breaks):

```
    <subnode1>
      <value1>101</value1>
      <value2>102</value2> 
      <value3>103</value3> 
    </subnode1>
    <subnode2>
      <value1>501</value1>
      <value2>502</value2> 
      <value3>503</value3> 
    </subnode2>
```

I cannot find such a function in Delphi 10.

Is there such a function?

Or what is the best approach to implement one in Delphi 10?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem - what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is an XY problem?

Comment: I would like to extract all the content (text) between e.g. `<node1>` and `</node1>` as string.

Comment: And what will you do with that?

Comment: I would like to extract this content block (this sub XML block) and save it as an independent XML structure, rename some nodes and then append it to another XML structure. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @user3384674 see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.CloneNode) can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *correct* way to handle this is to use an actual XML library, such as Delphi's native [`TXMLDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument) component or [`IXMLDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLDocument) interface (or any number of 3rd party XML libraries that are available for Delphi).  You can load your XML into it, then find the [`IXMLNode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode) for the `<node1>` element (or whichever element you want), and then read its [`XML`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.XML) property as needed.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.XMLDoc;

var
  XML: DOMString;
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  Node: IXMLNode;
begin
  XML := '<?xml version="1.0"?><main><node1>...</node1></main>';
  Doc := LoadXMLData(XML);
  Node := Doc.DocumentElement; // <main>
  Node := Node.ChildNodes['node1'];
  XML := Node.XML;
  ShowMessage(XML);
end;
```

Or:

```
uses
  ..., Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.xmldom, Xml.XMLDoc;

var
  XML: DOMString;
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  Node: IXMLNode;
  XPath: IDOMNodeSelect;
  domNode: IDOMNode;
begin
  XML := '<?xml version="1.0"?><main><node1>...</node1></main>';
  Doc := LoadXMLData(XML);
  XPath := Doc.DocumentElement.DOMNode as IDOMNodeSelect;
  domNode := XPath.selectNode('/main/node1');
  Result := TXMLNode.Create(domNode, nil, (Doc as IXmlDocumentAccess).DocumentObject);
  XML := Node.XML;
  ShowMessage(XML);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to extract. You can only do it for 1 node. With the loop, you can get the value between two tags as you wish.

```
function Parse(Text, Sol, Sag: string): String;
begin
  Delete(Text, 1, Pos(Sol, Text) + Length(Sol) - 1);
  Result := Copy(Text, 1, Pos(Sag, Text) - 1);
end;
```

Use of:
XML:

```
 <test>Stackoverflow</test>
```

Delphi:

```
Parse(XML, '<test>', '</test>') //result: Stackoverflow
```