# How to copy a sub node structure from one XML file to another XML file (merge two XML files)?

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing

I have the following two XML files:

**File1**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
  <node1>
    <subnode1>
      <value1>101</value1>
      <value2>102</value2> 
      <value3>103</value3> 
    </subnode1>
    <subnode2>
      <value1>501</value1>
      <value2>502</value2> 
      <value3>503</value3> 
    </subnode2>
  </node1>
</main>
```

**File2**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
  <node1>
    <subnode1>
      <value1>454</value1>
      <value2>471</value2> 
      <value3>498</value3> 
    </subnode1>
    <subnode2>
      <value1>723</value1>
      <value2>645</value2> 
      <value3>823</value3> 
    </subnode2>
  </node1>
</main>
```

In Delphi I would like to add the complete `<node1>...</node1>` structure of File2 to File1 renamed as `<node2>...</node2>`. So the result should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
  <node1>
    <subnode1>
      <value1>101</value1>
      <value2>102</value2> 
      <value3>103</value3> 
    </subnode1>
    <subnode2>
      <value1>501</value1>
      <value2>502</value2> 
      <value3>503</value3> 
    </subnode2>
  </node1>
  <node2>
    <subnode1>
      <value1>454</value1>
      <value2>471</value2> 
      <value3>498</value3> 
    </subnode1>
    <subnode2>
      <value1>723</value1>
      <value2>645</value2> 
      <value3>823</value3> 
    </subnode2>
  </node2>
</main>
```

I asked already how to extract the `<node1>...</node1>` block in the question
[How to extract the inner text and XML of node as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802155/how-to-extract-the-inner-text-and-xml-of-node-as-string)
(which was indeed a XY-problem, sorry about that) and I could work out a solution with manipulating the XML as strings.

But I suppose there might be a better solution working directly with the XML functionality. So how could I implement this in Delphi 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have parsed the XML files into [`TXMLDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument)/[`IXMLDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLDocument) objects, it is fairly trivial to clone/move [`IXMLNode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode) objects from one document to the other (see [`IXMLNode.CloneNode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.CloneNode), or [`IXMLNodeList.Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNodeList.Add) and [`IXMLNodeList.Remove()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNodeList.Remove)). Although you can't *rename* a node, you can *create* a new node with the desired name (see [`IXMLNode.AddChild()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.AddChild)), and then clone/move the old node's children underneath the new node.

You should not be using XML strings for these tasks. Manipulate the DOM tree instead.  So, you would get the `IXMLNode` for `<node1>` in File2, add a new `IXMLNode` for `<node2>` in File1, and then clone/move `<subnode1>` and `<subnode2>` from the `IXMLNode` in File2 to the `IXMLNode` in File1.

---

That being said, why are your elements named sequentially to begin with?  `<node>`, `<subnode>`, `<value>`, etc would suffice just fine.  You can have multiple `<node>`s, multiple `<subnode>`s, multiple `<value>`'s in one document as needed.  XML is good about using repeated element names.  You don't really need to use sequential numbers in element names, eg:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
  <node>
    <subnode>
      <value>101</value>
      <value>102</value> 
      <value>103</value> 
    </subnode>
    <subnode>
      <value>501</value>
      <value>502</value> 
      <value>503</value> 
    </subnode>
  </node>
  <node>
    <subnode>
      <value>454</value>
      <value>471</value> 
      <value>498</value> 
    </subnode>
    <subnode>
      <value>723</value>
      <value>645</value> 
      <value>823</value> 
    </subnode>
  </node>
</main>
```

If you really needed to differentiate by numbers, you could use attributes instead, eg:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
  <node id="1">
    <subnode id="1">
      <value id="1">101</value>
      <value id="2">102</value> 
      <value id="3">103</value> 
    </subnode>
    <subnode id="2">
      <value id="1">501</value>
      <value id="2">502</value> 
      <value id="3">503</value> 
    </subnode>
  </node>
  <node id="2">
    <subnode id="1">
      <value id="1">454</value>
      <value id="2">471</value> 
      <value id="3">498</value> 
    </subnode>
    <subnode id="2">
      <value id="1">723</value>
      <value id="2">645</value> 
      <value id="3">823</value> 
    </subnode>
  </node>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work if I use the default DOMVendor. However if I use Omni XML as  DOMVendor I will get an EXMLException with message 'NewChild was created from a different document than the one that created this node.' when the cloned node is added to the ChildNodes list. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I have formulated this in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160830/how-to-copy-a-sub-node-structure-from-one-xml-file-to-another-xml-file-merge-tw

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`IXMLNode.CloneNode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.CloneNode).

Here is a complete example:

```
uses XMLIntf, XMLDoc, xmldom;

procedure Test;
var
    XML1, XML2: DOMString;
    Doc1, Doc2: IXMLDocument;
    NewNode, Node1: IXMLNode;
    i: integer;
begin
    XML1 := '<?xml version="1.0"?><main><node1><subnode>1</subnode></node1></main>';
    Doc1 := LoadXMLData(XML1);
    NewNode := Doc1.DocumentElement.AddChild('node2');

    XML2 := '<?xml version="1.0"?><main><node1><subnode>2</subnode></node1></main>';
    Doc2 := LoadXMLData(XML2);
    Node1 := Doc2.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['node1'];

    // Clone nodes from Doc2 to Doc1
    for i := 0 to Node1.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
        NewNode.ChildNodes.Add(Node1.ChildNodes[i].CloneNode(true));

    Doc1.SaveToFile('merged.xml');
end;
```