# How to copy a sub node structure from one XML file to another XML file (merge two XML files) using Omni XML as DOMVendor

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing

I asked how to copy a sub node structure from one XML file to another XML file (merge the two XML files) in this question:

[How to copy a sub node structure from one XML file to another XML file (merge two XML files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820953/how-to-copy-a-sub-node-structure-from-one-xml-file-to-another-xml-file-merge-tw)

The useful and detailed answers from Remy Lebeau and Olivier work fine when I do not set the `DOMVendor`.

However, when I set the `DOMVendor` to `'Omni XML'`, I get an `EXMLException` error when the cloned node is added to the `ChildNodes` list:

> NewChild was created from a different document than the one that created this node.

The exception is raised in unit `Xml.Internal.OmniXML` in

```pascal
function OmniTXMLNode.appendChild(const NewChild: OmniIXMLNode): OmniIXMLNode;
var
  Node: OmniIXMLNode;
  SPrefix: string;
  URIIDCh, URIIDPa: TDicId;
begin
  // NewChild should be created from the same document than the one that created this node
  if (Self.OwnerDocument <> nil) and (NewChild.OwnerDocument <> nil) and (NewChild.OwnerDocument <> Self.OwnerDocument) then
    raise EXMLException.CreateParseError(WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR, MSG_E_WRONG_DOCUMENT, []);
```

Target platform is 64-bit Windows. I would like to use `'Omni XML'` because it seems to be much faster than `'MSXML'`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Clearly, Omni does not allow mixing nodes from different documents.  So, you will have to decouple the cloned node from the old document before inserting it into the new document. Otherwise, you won't be able to use cloning, you will have to manually duplicate the desired source nodes one at a time within the target document as needed.

Comment: Thanks! How do you decouple the cloned node from the old document?

Comment: I can't answer that. Maybe it can't be done, I don't know. You would have to check with the Omni source code (which I don't have) to see how the `OwnerDocument` is exposed.

Comment: Thank you! If I can't use cloning could you please let me know how you would manually duplicate the desired source nodes one at a time within the target document as needed?

Comment: Write a recursive loop. Starting with a given node, `AddChild()` its tag name into the new document where needed, then copy its attribute values to that new node, and then finally loop through its child nodes, repeating the add+copy for each of them specifying the new node as their parent. Really not that difficult.